# c++: From nested do-while loop to nested while loop

Tags: c++, nested, do-while

I have this guessing game program in c++. 
I did it in a nested do-while loop.
How can I make it in *while loop* instead of do while?

Comment: Works for me when I add #include <stdlib.h>. I get a loop when I enter a non integer for the number. To fix that you would need to check for errors on the input.

Comment: The name field cannot contain blanks as written. May want to read the whole line for the name.

Comment: do you want the nested loop to be a while loop instead of a do-while?

Comment: Yes Buck, that's what I want. I tried but I couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

I created a function for your game loop to make everything clearer.  Also note that srand() is looking for an unsigned int.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void rungame()
{
    int num = rand() % 10 + 0;
    int guess = -1;

    cout << "Guess a number between 0 - 10 : "<<endl;
    while (guess != num)
    {
        cin >> guess;
        if (guess > num)
        {
            cout << "Your guess is high . Guess again !"<<endl;
        }
        if (guess < num)
        {
            cout << "Your guess is low . Guess again !"<<endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand( (unsigned int) time(NULL) );
    string choice = "Yes";
    while (choice == "Yes")
    {
     rungame();
     cout << "That is Correct, You win"<<endl;
        cout <<"\nWould you like to give the game another try ? (Yes or no)"<<endl;
        cin>>choice;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code for guessing a number into a function (e.g. `guessTheNumber`). Call it once initially. After it breaks out of the loop, it will return from the function. After that function call, ask the user if they want to try again. If yes, then call the function (e.g. `guessTheNumber`) again until the user says no. Once they say no, quit your program. This will reduce it down to one `do/while` loop.

Pseudocode:

```
int main()
{
   guessTheNumber();
   Do you want to guess again?
   if choice is yes, call guessTheNumber();
   else
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be from Singapore.. anyway, you can try this.

```
cout << "Guess a number between 0 - 10 : "<<endl;
cin >> guess;

while(true)
{
        if (guess > num)
            cout << "Your guess is high . Guess again !"<<endl;
        else if (guess < num)    
            cout << "Your guess is low . Guess again !"<<endl;            
        else
        {
            cout << "That is Correct, You win"<<endl;
            cout <<"\nWould you like to give the game another try ? (Yes or no)"<<endl;
            cin>>choice;
            if (choice.compare("no")==0  //If user enter any other inputs, game continues
                 break;
        }
        cin >> guess;
}
```

There are several ways you can implement this. In your case, since you are already checking the condition whether num==guess, you can remove that checking in the while loop. Use the while loop for the sole purpose of looping.

Explicitly set "guess" to a number which cannot possibly be "num" (E.g set guess=-1) feels abit like hard-coding. :-P

Comment: while(true) works, but infinite loops are not a great idea.  They are actually adding work, because you cannot reuse a value to naturally "trigger" the exit condition built into WHILE !

Answer (score 0):

Made sure there were logical defaults before the while statement. Other than that, the code is yours.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
srand(time(0));
int guess;
string choice , name;

cout << "What is your name ?"<<endl;
cin>>name;
cout << "*******************************"<<endl;
cout << "Welcome to the Hi-Lo Game , "<<name<<endl;
cout << "*******************************"<<endl;

choice = "Yes";
while (choice=="Yes")
{
    int num = rand() % 10 + 0;
    cout << "Guess a number between 0 - 10 : "<<endl;
    guess = -1;
    while (guess !=num)
    {
        cin >> guess;

        if (guess > num)
        {
            cout << "Your guess is too high . Guess again !"<<endl;
        }
        else if (guess < num)
        {
            cout << "Your guess is too low . Guess again !"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "That is Correct, You win"<<endl;
        }
    }

    cout <<"\nWould you like to give the game another try ? (Yes or no)"<<endl;

    cin>>choice;

}


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While loop is usually used if the number of iterations of the loop is not known in advance, but depends on the fulfillment of specified conditions. 
The basic form of a while loop:

while (condition)

{

```
    block of statements
```

}

statement following the block

• In these types of loop condition tested at the beginning of a block of statements loop is repeated until the condition is met. 
• The condition is a logical expression whose result must be logical data (type bool). When the result becomes a logical false (false, 0), skipping the block command loop and the program continues from the first statement after the statement block of the loop. 
• As in the loop while the condition tested at the beginning it may happen that a block of statements in the loop does not execute even once.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your nested loop with the following one. (Only nested one, not the 1st Do-while, as u said in comments above)

```
  guess=-1; //
while(guess!=num)
    {
     cin >> guess;

     if (guess > num)
     {
        cout << "Your guess is high . Guess again !"<<endl;
     }
     else if (guess < num)
     {
        cout << "Your guess is low . Guess again !"<<endl;
     }
     else
     {
         cout << "That is Correct, You win"<<endl;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

The way you have it set up after the user says they want to play again, you need to reinitialize `num`, otherwise `guess` will always equal `num`.
After that set `guess` to something that `num` will never be like -1.

Also think about how a do-while differs from a while.  A do-while does something once, then checks a condition.  A while loops checks a condition first, then does something if the condition is satisfied.  This feels like an assignment (or exercise) so i'm not going to write it, but you should have enough information to solve this problem :)